# Hibernate - Remove the where condition field from hibernate setter(POJO) class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have executed select query with where condition in hibernate. It returns the value in list  which contains where condition field also. I no need the where condition field in the list. how can i remove it.

Query I used :

```
select cityname,cityid from citymaster where stateid ='2';
```

it returns cityname,cityid,stateid in the list. But I need cityname,cityid

Hibernate :

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("select cityname,cityid from Citymaster where stateid ='2'");
        query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Citymaster.class));
        List cityMasterList = query.list();
        Citymaster[] cma = cityMasterList.toArray();
```

in cma - cityname,cityid,stateid in the array. But I need cityname,cityid.

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt that this query retrieves the stateid. I've executed a whole lot of similar queries using Hibernate, and they just return the columns in the select clause.

Of course, if your `Citymaster` class has a `stateid` property, it won't magically disappear from the class just because you didn't query for it. All the returned instances will just have the default value in this property (the one you set in the no-arg constructor of `Citymaster`, or 0 or null if you don't set any specific value in the constructor, depending on the type of the `stateid` field).

If you want to make sure, just remove the query.setResultTransformer call, and inspect the content of the list. It should contain instances of `Object[]` containing two elements.

Answer (score 0):

It is retriving the value because you have set method for stateid in your citymaster.
So you must not have to write set method for it in your Citymaster class.
Remove that set method & check one. You will get your output.